# Class DataSource is missing when executing Maven install to generate maven-jaxb2-plugin: 0.8.3

Tags: java, maven

This question has a lot of similar variants in our community but none of the solutions below helped me yet. So I had to ask it as a new one.

So I was trying to install and build a project that is maintained by Maven by running  `mvn install -am -pl my-project -f pom.xml -e`. However, it was being blocked by the modules that need `maven-jaxb2-plugin`. The error trace says:

```
Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.3:generate (default) on project sub-module: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.3:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.3:generate: javax/activation/DataSource
```

I've set up this plugin like:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.3</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xjc</schemaDirectory>
            <generatePackage>${root-package}.xjc</generatePackage>
            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc</generateDirectory>
            <strict>false</strict>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <args>
              <arg>-XtoString</arg>
              <arg>-Xequals</arg>
              <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
              <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
              <arg>-Xmergeable</arg>
              <arg>-XlistAddHasMethod</arg>
            </args>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.0</version>
              </plugin>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>xjc</groupId>
                <artifactId>list-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Also, since I'm coding on IntelliJ, here's the project structure:

- SDK: openjdk-18
- Language Level: 8
- Maven: 3.9.1

I checked my directory that stores `javax.activation`. It does exist but just doesn't include `DataSource`.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using a 10 year old plugin instead of more up-to-date one? https://central.sonatype.com/search?smo=true&q=org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2

Comment: Idk, it's big project setup that my boss has been using for decades. i need to make sure it works before having new incompatibility

Comment: Then you should not start with openjdk-18 ... and JDK 8 ... do you get it compiled with older JDK's like JDK7 etc. ?

Comment: There would be another issue: ` Source option 7 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.` and `Target option 7 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.`

Comment: As I mentioned you have to use an old JDK because newer JDKs moved forward. First get your build running with JDK7 (from AZUL or alike) and clean up code /upgrade deps and afterwords migrate to JDK11 first and afterwards to JDK17 and so on....

Comment: Ok, I will try, is there a way to install JDK7 on intelliJ?

Comment: You should be able to configure IntelliJ to use JDK7...